# Moving airphone display panel mount to a stud which currently has a switch panel

Tags: electrical, wiring, doorbell

[image: Airphone display]

My airphone bell display is currently mounted as shown. I would like to move it about a foot to the right of where it currently is. There is a switch panel on the same stud. The box on which the display is mounted is fairly deep (image in imgur link). Will this be an issue?

https://imgur.com/a/umDv5GP

Comment: The only problem might be driving nails/screws into wires, but that should be very low chance, if careful.

Comment: Thank you @crip659 . I managed to move the box with the help of a handyman. It took some time and exploring, had to move some wires out of the way and drill a hole through a stud, but managed to get it exactly where I wanted it.